# fs promises fail in pm2

Tags: node.js, fs, pm2

I do a project and use fs/promises, if I run the server with node everithing is OK, but I want to start the project witj pm2 and get an error

```
    { Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises'
2|server |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
2|server |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:61:29)
2|server |     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2|server |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vr_system/filestorage/vr/utils/helper.js:2:18)
2|server |     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
2|server |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
2|server |     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
2|server |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
2|server |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
2|server |     at Module.require (module.js:596:17) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

I'm not an expert, but I assumed that pm2 is running projects with their own node_modules, so go to where pm2 is installed

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2
```

Then, I opened node_modules to look for the fs dir and see what happened, but I found the following dir with the next files:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fs.realpath/LICENSE
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fs.realpath/package.json
```

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fs.realpath/Readme

The next code is index,js:

```
module.exports = realpath
realpath.realpath = realpath
realpath.sync = realpathSync
realpath.realpathSync = realpathSync
realpath.monkeypatch = monkeypatch
realpath.unmonkeypatch = unmonkeypatch

var fs = require('fs')
var origRealpath = fs.realpath
var origRealpathSync = fs.realpathSync

var version = process.version
var ok = /^v[0-5]\./.test(version)
var old = require('./old.js')

function newError (er) {
  return er && er.syscall === 'realpath' && (
    er.code === 'ELOOP' ||
    er.code === 'ENOMEM' ||
    er.code === 'ENAMETOOLONG'
  )
}

function realpath (p, cache, cb) {
  if (ok) {
    return origRealpath(p, cache, cb)
  }

  if (typeof cache === 'function') {
    cb = cache
    cache = null
  }
  origRealpath(p, cache, function (er, result) {
    if (newError(er)) {
      old.realpath(p, cache, cb)
    } else {
      cb(er, result)
    }
  })
}

function realpathSync (p, cache) {
  if (ok) {
    return origRealpathSync(p, cache)
  }

  try {
    return origRealpathSync(p, cache)
  } catch (er) {
    if (newError(er)) {
      return old.realpathSync(p, cache)
    } else {
      throw er
    }
  }
}

function monkeypatch () {
  fs.realpath = realpath
  fs.realpathSync = realpathSync
}

function unmonkeypatch () {
  fs.realpath = origRealpath
  fs.realpathSync = origRealpathSync
}
```

How Do I need change this to include fs/promises

Or I'm wrong and this isn't the solution

Please help me

Comment: Im having a similar problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: No, stop using and better start using nginx, isn't the same, but I couldn't solve this